# How to display a group of images from drawable to let the user pick one (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, image, picker

I currently have an activity with a horizontal scrollview, and inside it I have an add button (ImageView) to let the user add some images to the same horizontal scrollview after clicking it. How can I display a group of images from app resources (such as drawable) as a sort of "pop up" to let the user pick one, without changing the current activity?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you want. But try creating a custom alert dialog with image views in it. And set the src of the imageview from the drawable.

Comment: I tried to work with the alertdialog and Picasso library, but even after setting the dialog layoutParameters to MATCH_PARENT it keeps resizing itself to the size of one image. This way the dialog is really small and I have to keep scrolling forever. I'll just work with another activity use startactivityforresult. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by inflating a custom xml layout (containing a GridView) on an AlertDialog. To display the images on the GridView you need to create and set a custom adapter to it. The adapter shall have a function getView(), which will return each of the Views to be shown on Grid cells. You can also use Picasso Library to load the images.

Here is a brief tutorial

http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/gridview-tutorial-using-the-picasso-library.html

Hint: Remember to define the number of columns of the grid, and calculate the size of each image based on the screen size. This way you can fit the amount you like on each row. You can do this for both portrait and landscape orientations by overriding the function onConfigurationChanged.

Hint 2: Remember a GridView already has the scroll property, which needs to be activated (android:scrollbars="horizontal"). Using a ScrollView as parent of a GridView will cause it to wrap the image, even with MATCH_PARENT property activated, causing layout problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create  recyclerView with horizontal layout. The adapter of the recyclerView will have the functionality to implement a button click. The onClick of the button will add items to the adapter. These items may contain your required images.On every button click you need to call notifyDataSetChanged.